# Quasar: some fontawesome icons are not available

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, quasar-framework, quasar

I use some fontawesome icons in a quasar project.

I import them as specified in the quasar doc:

> Webfont icons are available through @quasar/extras package. You don’t need to import it in your app, just configure /quasar.config.js as indicated above.
>
> Adding more than one set:
>
> extras: [
> 'material-icons',
> 'mdi-v6',
> 'ionicons-v4', // last webfont was available in v4.6.3
> 'eva-icons',
> 'fontawesome-v6',
> 'themify',
> 'line-awesome',
> 'bootstrap-icons'
> ]

As a result I do have a set of icons from the v6, unfortunately some are missing.

For instance:

[image]

is not available:

[image]

Why is this so and how could I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Pro icon.
To use it, you'll need a subscription to a Pro-level plan or a perpetual Pro license.